# How can I make Spring testcontext framework use multiple data sources?

Tags: java, unit-testing, spring, integration-testing, spring-test

I'm trying to integration test my application with Spring TestContext framework. I have done this by extending `AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests`, as usual. However, my application has three different data sources (with names like xDataSource, yDataSource, zdataSource), så when I try to run the test, the autowiring of data source in `AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests` won't work, since it looks for a Data Source with autowire-by-type, but finds three, so it does not know which one to choose.

Is there any way to get Spring TestContext Framework to use three data sources? If so; how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I figured it out. The answer to this question is twofold. Firstly, extending `AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests` won't work. This is because it needs a single data source for creating the `SimpleJdbcTemplate` for verifying stuff with simple JDBC queries in the test. Since I don't use this feature in this test, I could replace `extends AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests` with the collowing configuration:

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations = "classpath:applicationContext.xml")
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@TestExecutionListeners({
    DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class,
    DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener.class,
    TransactionalTestExecutionListener.class
})
@Transactional
public class IntegrationTest {
  ...
}
```

The combination of these annotations gives the same setup as extending `AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests`.

The second part was understanding that since I have three data sources, I also need all three so be referenced by the same `PlatformTransactionManager`. I have distributed transactions. This is impossible with a `DataSourceTransactionManager`, so I had to use a `JtaTransactionManager`.

Comment: Note that you don't need to specify `@TestExecutionListeners` - these listeners are enabled by default.

Answer (score 1):

The `AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests` class is autowired to a single data source only to allow the convenience of providing an injected `JdbcTemplate` object. You can override the `setDataSource(DataSource dataSource)` method from `AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests` in your test subclass and specify the data source to use like this:

```
@Resource(name = "dataSource")
public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) { 
  this.jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource); 
}
```

You just have to provide the name of the one data source Spring should use for the `jdbcTemplate` convenience methods. If extending `AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests` is more convenient than other methods mentioned above, then you can force it to work by just choosing one of your data sources.

I found these details in Spring Jira ticket [#SPR-4634](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-4634).

Answer (score 0):

You can define one of the data-sources as `primary="true"` in your xml, and it will be chosen.

If you need all threem then you cannot rely on autowiring - use `ReflectionTestUtils` to set it manually in your tests.

Comment: I'm not necessarily relying on autowiring, but the thing is that `AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests` autowires a data source. This is for use in the simpleJdbcTemplate the class offers for doing simple queries in the test. If I setup the test using only annotations, the problem disappears. However, I want all datasources to run in the same transaction.

Comment: Well, ReflectionTestUtils should work then. Perhaps you should also obtain the dao and set it there.